# Pulsar NS200 (2018) Pulls towards left

Tags: alignment

I know it's dangerous to take off your hands from the handlebar and riding on the roads. But just to give a check 
When i try to leave my hands from my bike the handle pulls it to the left side of the road. Eg (if I'm on the extreme right lane and leave my hands the bike would go to the extreme left side of the road.

I had a fall once after which i had done all necessary work (fork press/bend, changing of cone set etc)

But still I'm facing the issue and addition to that i just inspected my front tyres so it has started getting wear from right side of the bike

Also when going into the right cornering front wheel tries to leave the traction.

I showed it to the mechanic and also service center when they ride it they it's alright.. i don't know from where that magic happens

Can anyone suggest what would be the exact cause..???

Comment: My ns 200 same problm Pls tell what was the problem ?

Comment: There can be different issues. However, please check your fork for bends. If not then probably your suspension and tyre threads.

Answer (score 1):

Either the forks are bent or the frame.

You need to set it on a jig and take measurements to find out where.